# Como unir diversas variáveis em uma só em php e passar para JQuery em um link

Tags: php, jquery

Consultei sobre o assunto e até consegui encontrar algumas formas mas nada que conseguisse solucionar o meu caso, vou tentar ser direto para facilitar.
Tenho uma tabela onde listo algumas visitas de algumas empresas, tenho as visitas dos tipos RTV e ATV e estou somando as visitas e colocando nessa tabela nos respectivos campos nas datas, cada soma representa as visitas feitas, no exemplo abaixo o dia 18/09 teve 3 visitas ATV.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Cada visita dessa tem um `ID`, ou seja, `3 IDs` e o que estou tentando fazer é unir esses `ID´s` em uma mesma variável, fiz os selects necessários e criei essa estrutura para armazena-los, mas não de forma dinâmica, estou fazendo esse select dentro de um `loop` e ele está assim, no caso da visita ATV:

```
     $sqlMontaLinkATV = "SELECT supVisitaRtv.IdVisita FROM supVisitaRtv WHERE Tipo = 'ATV' AND supVisitaRtv.Data = ? AND IdEmpresa = ? ";   
     $arrayParamLinkATV = array($DataInc, $IdEmpresa);  
     $ResultadoLinkATV  = $crud->getSQLGeneric($sqlMontaLinkATV, $arrayParamLinkATV, TRUE);
```

O resultado dessa pesquisa estou vendo assim com um `print_r($ResultadoLinkATV)`:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [IdVisita] => 33 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [IdVisita] => 34 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [IdVisita] => 37 ) )
```

Onde tenho os ID´s das visitas que preciso, tentei fazer a inserção delas em uma variável dessa forma:

```
 $IdVisita = array();
 array_push($IdVisita, $ResultadoLinkATV[0]->IdVisita);
```

Espero ter conseguido explicar de forma satisfatória.

Comment: No seu banco o '3' é um valor real ou você chega no '3' somando registros de visitas na hora da consulta?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Com base nos dados da pergunta, o resultado da sua consulta SQL é da seguinte forma:

```
$ResultadoLinkATV = [
    (object) ["idVisita" => 33],
    (object) ["idVisita" => 34],
    (object) ["idVisita" => 37]
];
```

Você pode obter a lista de ids através da função `array_column` do PHP:

```
$ids = array_column($ResultadoLinkATV, "idVisita"); // [33, 34, 37]
```

Assim, `$ids` será um *array* da forma `[33, 34, 37]`. Se precisar os valores como *string*, pode converter para JSON:

```
$ids_string = json_encode($ids); // "[33,34,37]"
```

Ou utilizar o `implode`.

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/bQR3eB).

Comment: Olá @Anderson Carlos Woss, estou usando o PHP versão 5.6.22 e não consegui ver o resultado como exemplificado, preciso de alguma permissão especial?
Obrigado pela dica.

Comment: Tanto `json_encode` quanto `array_column` estão presentes nesta versão, então não veio motivos para não funcionar. Como tentou fazer, de fato?

Comment: Fiz dessa forma:

$IdVisita = array_column($ResultadoLinkATV, "IdVisita");
print_r($IdVisita);
O resultado é esse: Array ( )

Comment: E não foi exibido nada? O `var_dump` de `$ResultadoLinkATV` é o mesmo da pergunta?

Comment: Não foi um var_dump mas assim print_r($ResultadoLinkATV);

Comment: O que importa é o resultado. É o mesmo?

Comment: Sim, é o mesmo.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66276/discussion-between-anderson-carlos-woss-and-adventistapr).

Answer (score 0):

Este problema poderia ser resolvido usando a função COUNT do SQL

```
SELECT COUNT(supVisitaRtv.IdVisita) AS qnt FROM supVisitaRtv WHERE Tipo = 'ATV' AND supVisitaRtv.Data = ? AND IdEmpresa = ?;
```

assim, o próprio banco faz o calculo de quantas visitas foram realizadas do tipo ATV pela empresa e em certa data informada;

Comment: Não acho que seja esse o problema. Ele precisa armazenar em uma mesma variável os valores dos ids retornados, não contar a quantidade de registros.

Comment: Olá @Igor Igor Martinelli, obrigado pela sugestão, mas foi como o  Anderson Carlos Woss comentou, não preciso de soma, isso eu já tenho.